# how to specify start for a pandas time series with timedelta index?

Tags: pandas

It seems that I can't specify a start for resampling a series with timedelta index.

```py
s = pd.Series([1, 1, 1], index=[pd.Timedelta("1min"), pd.Timedelta("4min"), pd.Timedelta("8min")])
s
```

```
0 days 00:01:00    1
0 days 00:04:00    1
0 days 00:08:00    1
dtype: int64
```

```py
s.resample("30S").count()
```

```
0 days 00:01:00    1
0 days 00:01:30    0
0 days 00:02:00    0
```

How can I specify the start from "0 days 00:00:00"?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest method is to `reindex` your Series and use `pd.timedelta_range` to create the new index from `0` to `s.index.max()`:

```
>>> s.resample("30S").count() \
     .reindex(pd.timedelta_range(0, s.index.max(), freq='30S'), fill_value=0)
0 days 00:00:00    0
0 days 00:00:30    0
0 days 00:01:00    1
0 days 00:01:30    0
0 days 00:02:00    0
0 days 00:02:30    0
0 days 00:03:00    0
0 days 00:03:30    0
0 days 00:04:00    1
0 days 00:04:30    0
0 days 00:05:00    0
0 days 00:05:30    0
0 days 00:06:00    0
0 days 00:06:30    0
0 days 00:07:00    0
0 days 00:07:30    0
0 days 00:08:00    1
Freq: 30S, dtype: int64
```